# How should I route in this KOHANA?

Tags: php, routes, kohana, kohana-3.3

apache error

```
**Not Found**

The requested URL /status was not found on this server.
```

{maindir}/index.php is working

My application/bootstrap.php

```
Route::set(
        'status', 'status'
    )->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'solution',
        'action'     => 'status'
    )
);
```

My /application/classes/Controller/Solution.php

```
class Controller_Solution extends Controller_Base
{

    public function action_status()
    {
    ..........................................
```

Comment: So other routes work just not this one?

Comment: Ok, this might be an indicator, that your `base_url` in bootstrap.php and/or `RewriteBase` in .htaccess might not be correct

Comment: Fixed, .htaccess problem